# Arrange boys and girls with no boy adjacent to other boy

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

There are total M girls and N boys.

We need to find the number of ways we can arrange boys and girls in a row such that no two boys should be present which are adjacent to each other.

If no such arrangement is possible, I need to tell that too.

So how to approach this problem ?

Example : For 3 Girls and 2 Boys there are 72 ways.

Comment: How did you obtain $72$ ways for three boys and two girls?  The number is too large.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You're right - I think this is the answer for 3 girls and 2 boys.

Comment: @user84413 Yeah right !! Corrected

Comment: Smells like a problem from a programming contest.

Comment: M! * (M+1)!/(M+1-N)!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

1) First arrange the girls in a row.

2) Next choose the N gaps for the boys.

3) Then arrange the boys in those gaps.

Comment: Can there be some direct formula ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: @mat7  How many ways can $m$ girls be arranged in a row?  How many gaps are there between successive girls?  How many additional gaps are formed at the end of the row?  In how many ways can $n$ of these gaps be filled?  In how many ways can $n$ boys be arranged in a row?